# Returning several variables from a Sub or Function and passing them to a different Sub

Tags: vba

I have roughly laid out the following code in VBA:

```
Sub Main()
Sheets("SheetA").Range("A1") = Test(250)
```

> I want this to be Param_A from Test(25)

```
Sheets("SheetA").Range("B1") = Test(250)
```

> I want this to be Param_B from Test(250)

```
End Sub

Sub Test(speed)
Param_A = 1 * speed
Param_B = 2 * speed
End Sub
```

> I want Test() to return Param_A and Param_B such that I can pass those to Main(). Param_A and Param_B will vary depending on what speed I input into Test()

I feel like this should be such a simple task, yet I cannot get my head around how VBA approaches this. I have read that I can use either a Sub or Function, yet neither seem to work here....

Please can someone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain your use case - otherwise there are tons of possible solutions to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the values *by reference*:

```vb
Sub Test( _
    Byval speed As Double, _
    ByRef Param_A As Double, _
    ByRef Param_B As Double)

    Param_A = 1 * speed
    Param_B = 2 * speed

End Sub
```

Then:

```vb
Sub Main()

    Dim Param_A As Double
    Dim Param_B As Double

    speed = 250
    Test speed, Param_A, Param_B

    Sheets("SheetA").Range("A1") = Param_A
    Sheets("SheetA").Range("B1") = Param_B

End Sub
```